# Can't pass user data in callback using Glade

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have an app I'm making with pygtk and Glade.

I have a radio button series I'm trying to get working. I'm getting stumped at trying to pass user data after a button is toggled. The callback works fine, but is not being sent the user data entered next to the handler in the user data field in glade.

Just as a simple test, I did this as a part of a class:

```
def on_output_toggled(self, widget, data=None):
    print data
```

within glade, there is a radiobutton that is set to signal "toggle" with on_output_toggled in the Handler and m4b as the user data.

Expected terminal output from this after the radiobutton is selected is:

```
m4b
```

What I get is:

```
None
```

What am I doing wrong. Nothing is being passed on the the callback other than the widget itself.

Thanks,
Narnie

Answer (score 1):

The "user data" you enter in Glade should actually only be the name of other widgets (or actions, or objects) defined in that Glade file. In your case, there would need to be an object named "m4b" somewhere in your Glade file.

Comment: Yes, I have found this is true, which stinks because if you are setting it up by hand rather than using Glade, you could pass any user information you wanted to your callback rather than have to pass a function/object. Glade is quite limiting in this regard and I'm puzzled as to why it would be designed this way. I might file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this sort of problem too, my solution is connect signals manually.
I use perl-gtk3 ,Python works theoretically.

```
...
my $button = $builder->get_object("button");
$button->signal_connect(clicked=>\&on_output_toggled,"m4b");
...
```